# Python splat operator error

Tags: python, splat

I have a map iterator `gmm` and I'm sending it to a function called `fisher_vector` but I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: fisher_vector() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'means', 'covs', and 'w'
```

I call the function in this line:

```
return np.float32([fisher_vector(file, *gmm) for file in files])
```

The function is the following:

```
def fisher_vector(samples, means, covs, w):
    s0, s1, s2 =  likelihood_statistics(samples, means, covs, w)
    T = samples.shape[0] ...
```

I should receive `gmm` unpacked and it should contain `means, covs, w` but I receive the mentioned error.

`gmm` contains three lists: `means, covs, w`. `means` is a list of 3 elements, each element is size 128, `covs` is a list of 3 elements, each element is size 128 and `w` is a list of 3 elements, each element is size 1

Here is an example of what means contains:

```
[  24.13298798   20.21194077   19.60643387   20.92037392   22.41041565
   20.10162354   20.14926147   21.63036919   31.96772003   27.53086281
   25.40476799   27.28077888   30.47002029   25.3988018    23.52041626
   25.41398811   48.02087784   28.68225288   19.95660019   19.55717659
   24.30649185   25.4529705    28.90529633   39.54360199   23.47204971
```

Comment: Show what `gmm` actually is.

Comment: @Carcigenicate description updated